# BigCommerce API - Unable to get product list

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, bigcommerce

Obviously there is something obvious I'm missing here.  I figured it would be this easy to query the BigCommerce API using OAuth v2... however the response I get is: {"error":"You are authorized but your scope does not include this resource."}

The Token being used was returned from the Auth callback with a scope of: store_v2_orders store_v2_products store_v2_customers store_v2_content store_v2_marketing store_v2_information_read_only users_basic_information store_v2_default

Obviously the token has the proper scope.  What am I sending incorrectly that is causing this to not have access?  I've searched all over the interwebs and tried many alternate configurations but this one feels the closest to the solution.  Any ideas?

```
string storeID = "store-abc123";
string clientID = "asdfdsafsdafdsafdsaf";
string token = "kljsdflkjsdflkjsdflkj";

var client = new RestClient( "https://api.bigcommerce.com/" );
var request = new RestRequest( "/stores/" + storeID + "/v2/products/", Method.GET );

request.AddParameter( "scope", "store_v2_products" );

request.AddHeader( "Accept", "application/json" );
request.AddHeader( "X-Auth-Client", clientID );
request.AddHeader( "X-Auth-Token", token );

var response = client.Execute( request );
```

Comment: Fyi: The authorization data here is swapped out with dummy data for the concern of security.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it turns out this was my fault.

The line

```
string storeID = "store-abc123";
```

should have simply been

```
string storeID = "abc123";
```